# c#: getter/setter

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I saw something like the following somewhere, and was wondering what it meant. I know they are getters and setters, but want to know why the string Type is defined like this. Thanks for helping me.

```
public string Type { get; set; }
```

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/12/04/c-3-0-features-automatic-properties.aspx

Comment: This is called an Auto-Property, have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: This is the definition of a property named `"Type"`, the .NET type of which is `System.string`. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: I think that he might be confusing the naming of the Auto-Property with the Reflection class System.Type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/49/properties/3365/auto-implemented-properties#t=201610041453344442997

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Those are [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) (Auto Properties for short).

The compiler will auto-generate the equivalent of the following simple implementation:

```
private string _type;

public string Type
{
    get { return _type; }
    set { _type = value; }
}
```

Comment: @barlop as someone coming from google, with no clue, what needs to be updated? Is M. Hassans answer what you mean? thanks.

Comment: @Aethenosity in retrospect I think it's ok.. I was thinkinig in terms of examples of getter setter.  The questioner has a valid case of getter setter that is far more succinct(as a one liner/ no second field necessary).. You can also write `public int b { get { return b * 2; } }`  no second field necessary.  But I think when you have the setter with a body then you need the second field.  And this one shows  a setter with a body. Though it does the same as the questioner's one liner.

Comment: @Aethenosity there is also c# 7 whereby sure you still need the second field when the setter has a body, but it has a `=>` syntax and no return keyword.  Though that wasn't what I had in mind.  I had in mind the second field being unnecessary, though I have since found that the second field is necessary sometimes. In the example here the second field isn't necessary('cos a default setter with no body would do this), but the answerer was putting it in(setter body and second field),  to explain to the questioner what their line without the second field was doing.

Answer (score 42):

That is an [auto-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) and it is the shorthand notation for this:

```
private string type;
public string Type
{
  get { return this.type; }
  set { this.type = value; }
}
```

Comment: ... except that the backing field is not accessible.

Comment: ... which is why it is called the backing _field_.

Comment: Nevertheless, you should be able see it as `<Type>k__BackingField` with reflection.

Answer (score 35):

**In C# 6:**

It is now possible to declare the auto-properties just as a field:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Ropert";
```

Read-Only Auto-Properties

```
public string FirstName { get;} = "Ropert";
```

Answer (score 21):

```cs
public string Type { get; set; }
```

is no different than doing

```cs
private string _Type;

public string Type
{    
  get { return _Type; }
  set { _Type = value; }
}
```

Comment: Is this pass by value or reference?

Comment: @MericOzcan string is always pass by value. Same for all the basic types. int, double, bool etc.

Answer (score 8):

This means that the compiler defines a backing field at runtime. This is the syntax for auto-implemented properties.

More Information: [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

Answer (score 5):

It's an automatically backed property, basically equivalent to:

```cs
private string type;
public string Type
{
   get{ return type; }
   set{ type = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a lambda expression

```
public string Type
{
    get => _type;
    set => _type = value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

These are called auto properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Functionally (and in terms of the compiled IL), they are the same as properties with backing fields.

Comment: Can you still reference the private _type or type within the class, or you just use Type?

Comment: No, BUT you can specify the modifier for the auto property: public string Type { get; private set; }

Comment: You would be unable to access _type in this case.

Comment: So in that case this.Type = "foo"; should be OK, but from outside instance.Type = "foo"; will not.. These auto props are definitely a helpful addition to the language.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the release of C# 6, you can now do something like this for private properties.

```
public constructor()
{
   myProp = "some value";
}

public string myProp { get; }
```

Comment: you can set initial value directly in C# 6:  public string myProp { get; } ="some value") without constructor;