# passing variables form to form private to global in c#?

Tags: c#, forms, variables, global, private

Been working on a simple c# windows app program. I have been able to pass a few variables from one form to the next and use them using `form2 y = new form2(passingVariable); y.ShowDialog();` and then on the next form `public form2(string myVariable)`. However this method only allows me to use the variable within those curly braces. Currently I am trying to pass it to the next form in line. However it won't let me use the variable when I try to pass it into the next form using the code line I provided above. It gives me the error   The name 'userName' does not exist in the current context   I have a lot of source code and didn't know what exactly was needed for me to share so here is the [**link**](http://mysourcecode.webng.com/) to my webng.com account with a very simple web page set up with my source code if anyone needs to review it.

Comment: Please use pastebin or something similar for dumping code offsite.  It formats the code in a readable way.  Also be sure when you paste into pastebin that your code is properly delineated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating another variable on that current form to store that Username and then assign the username passed into that variable. Your constructor will be like this then:

```
private string username;

public talkingWithProgram(string userName, string pcName)
{
InitializeComponent();
this.Text = pcName;
programQuestion.Text = "Whatcha wanna talk about \n" + userName + "?";
this.userName = userName;
}

sportsCategories y = new sportsCategories(userName);
```

Creating a new sportsCategories class now passes userName from this context, which has the value from the previous form. Currently it looks like you're referring to the userName in the constructor which is in the method context and out of scope outside.

Comment: Thank you so very much @Knightwisp :) this solved the error message I was having. as soon as I plugged in the 'private string username;' and the 'this.userName = userName' however after plugging that information into my program there is a new error message that reads No overload for 'sport_click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Comment: Your code has a sports_Click() method. Is it the same one? Maybe it's a typo. Try making userName protected or even public so it's available to other classes in the namespace. Also, declare "public string userName;" in the right place; that is after "DialogResult result;". Make it "sportsCategories y = new sportsCategories(this.userName);"

Comment: To be honest, the code is a little difficult to read but try the above.

Comment: I added the code exactly like you showed me to do. I fixed the new error by adding 'object sender, EventArgs e' to the parameters for my click event that opens my 'sportsCategories' form.

Comment: Yes, that's the method for your button. Makes sense.

Comment: sorry about the difficulty reading the code. I'm still very new to this web site and I didn't know how to properly post my code without making it a great big hassle. Thank you for helping even with the inconvenience I have caused.

Comment: I have tried your code, and it gives no errors now. You should be able to continue with your development.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid setting specific variables in the constructor of a windows form.  In general, it is more customary to use [getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709072/c-getter-setter), or a function designated specifically for this purpose.

For example: If you can have the code `form2 y = new form2(passingVariable);` instead you can have the code

```
form2 y = new form2();
form2.SetMyVar(passingVariable);
```

OR, if you are using getters and setters:

```
form2 y = new form2();
form2.SetMyVar = passingVariable
```

That way, whenever you need to set or update the variable you can do it as long as you have a reference to the form.  Also, in said `SetMyVar()` function (if you choose that method), be sure to set a class variable.  *In your code, class variables go outside your functions, so that they are visible to all functions of that instance of the class.*

Answer (score 0):

initialize a variable in a class xyz
assign the values to them in constructor like

```
 String a1,b1=String.empty
  Class xyz
 {
   xyz(string a,string b)
  {       //constructor
   a1=a;
   b1=b;
    //Now use them in whole class
  }

 }
```

or if you want to use them in whole application then initialize them globally in Program.cs
then you can set and get values like

```
Program.a1="abc"    //assigning value
```

Comment: the strings a1 and b1 have to be inside the class definition. Also he probably should have the constructor public.