# public Class name[][] Method name{ get; set; } what does this mean in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

what does this mean in c# ?

```
public Extra_Bed_Configurations[][] extra_bed_configurations { get; set; }
```

Where Extra_Bed_Configurations Class have below properties.

```
public class Extra_Bed_Configurations
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Delcaring a [Jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)  property of that class type.

Comment: This mean that you have 2 dimension array of class Extra_Bed_Configurations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a jagged array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576759/what-is-a-jagged-array)

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand?

Comment: to be the most direct: the `{ get; set;}` part is not relevant for you. The `Extra_Bed_Configurations[][]` means, that this field is an Array of objects of type `Extra_Bed_Configurations[]`, which is just an Array of `Extra_Bed_Configurations`. (Also use google and the MSDN documentation for this stuff in the future)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a public property of type **jagged array** (array of arrays) `Extra_Bed_Configurations`

**Note:**

multidimenstional: `Extra_Bed_Configurations[,] extra_bed_configurations`

jagged: `Extra_Bed_Configurations[][] extra_bed_configurations`

---

sample declaration of a 2x2

```
extra_bed_configurations = new Extra_Bed_Configurations[][]{ 
        new Extra_Bed_Configurations[] {
            new Extra_Bed_Configurations() { type = "foo"}, 
            new Extra_Bed_Configurations() { type = "foo"}
        },
        new Extra_Bed_Configurations[] { 
            new Extra_Bed_Configurations() { type = "foo"}, 
            new Extra_Bed_Configurations() { type = "foo"}}
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

- `public` is access modifier, which doesn't restrict any access to
  property;
- `Extra_Bed_Configurations[][]` is [jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx);
- `extra_bed_configurations` is name of your property respectively;
- `{ get; set; }` means that this property is [auto-implemented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[][] is array of array.

```
1 -> A B C D
2 -> E F G H I J
3 -> K L M 
4 -> N O
```

Answer (score 0):

{get;set} after a member creates getters and setters for those types.
Here's the duplicate
[c#: getter/setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709072/c-getter-setter)